# IBM Worklight 5.0.5 - Unable to preview app in the MBS

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mbs

Using Worklight 5.0.5, I have issues with previewing my app in the Mobile Browser Simulator.

Once my app is deployed and I preview it in the MBS, nothing is displayed.
This occurs with every old and new project I create. Does anyone have an idea ? I didn't change my config at all.

This is the preview URL used:

> localhost:8080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/index.html?webpage=../apps/services/preview/TestHybridApp/ipad/1.0/&platform=ios.ipad

Right now all I can do is preview as common resource, which doesn't take into account the changes I did.

Comment: Can you try with the latest version of Worklight, 6.1.0.1?

Comment: Not for now I'm affraid, I looked into Worklight documentation and I think that this could be related to [Cordova plugin](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rad.worklight.doc%2Ftopics%2Ftpreview_Cordovawl.html), I'll investigate

Comment: What do you see in the Chrome dev tools? any errors? Also note that Cordova plug-ins (which utilize native code), will not work in the MBS, which only previews web resources. You will need to test your plug-in in a device or simulator/emulator.

Comment: Yes, I have 2 errors : 

**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "** and 

**"Uncaught ReferenceError: OpenLayers is not defined (dojo.js : 15)"**

Comment: The one about OpenLayers does not matter, it's about the MBS and not your application. The first one is interesting, it should also tell you in which file and line the error resides...

Comment: Yes, but it is a link I can't show you, it led to OpenLayer.js but the errors were removed with the operation done below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not encounter this in 5.0.5.x, but try the following:

1. Delete the native folder
2. Close Eclipse
3. Locate your temp folder ([Windows](http://appscout.pcmag.com/microsoft-windows/272405-find-the-temp-folder-in-vista-and-windows-7), [OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/how-do-i-find-out-the-system-temporary-directory))
4. Delete the `wlBuildResources` and wlPreview folders
5. Open Eclipse
6. Re-build

If you have custom native code in your native\ folder, be sure to back it up. 
More here (although it was written about Worklight 6.x, should work in 5.x...): [Worklight 6.1 - "All Build" fails and gives java.lang.NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394290/worklight-6-1-all-build-fails-and-gives-java-lang-nullpointerexception)

Comment: My MBS doesn't work anymore again, tried what you suggest without result. `[2014-06-13 09:17:19] Application 'X' deployed successfully with environment 'ipad'`. I don't have any idea, I just noticed that I don't have the *wlPreview* folder in Temp.

Comment: I can't preview my app in the MBS like the previous time, nothing is displayed. Can't even previews as common resource.

Comment: Did you close eclipse and delete the wlbuildrwsources folder?

Comment: Ok I think I got it, opened up the console and I got this : `Uncaught ReferenceError: OpenLayers is not defined  dojo.js:15` at the very start of the launching of the MBS. I'll try to reimport dojo. (yes I did all you suggested me the last time)

Comment: Nope, I tried to create a new project, but the dojo keeps failing at runtime with every new project (always the same error with OpenLayers) :( Do you have any idea (except update worklight) ?

Comment: OpenLayers is not relevant to your error. OpenLayers is used for displaying maps. Do you use maps? In addition, is this still obout Worklight 5.0.5? Upgrade.

Comment: LOL. Just created an Android environment to give it a try. Both apps (iPad & Android) are now well displayed in their own environments. And the *"Preview as common resource"* appears now in the catalog. I'll try this with my previous project, thanks for the support